# How to Hide the data in Angular2?

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-template

In my page I have three tabs,in my third tab I have used ng-select tag. I want to display only the 1.ng-select tag and the other tags namely 2. and 3. should be Hidden till I  select the data  in my 1.tag. Here is the pic for reference [Click Here To Display The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78jiD.png) And here is my code

```
<ng-select [options]="options" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Choose campaigns" [allowClear]="false" [multiple]='false' name="selectedCampaigns" style="width: 92%;margin-left: 10px;">
                    </ng-select> <br/>
                    <ng-select [options]="options" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Choose campaigns" [allowClear]="false" [multiple]='true' name="selectedCampaigns" style="width: 92%;margin-left: 10px;" [hidden]="selectedCampaigns">
                    </ng-select>
                    <ng-select [options]="options" class='filterDropDown' placeholder="Choose campaigns" [allowClear]="false" [multiple]='true' name="selectedCampaigns" style="width: 92%;margin-left: 10px;" [hidden]="selectedCampaigns">
                    </ng-select>
                    <button class="btn submitLogo" style="margin-top:15px;" (click)="compare()">Compare</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `([ngModel])` and `*ngIf` to do this.

```
<ng-select ([ngModel])=tab1 </ng-select>
<ng-select ([ngModel])=tab2 *ngIf="tab1" </ng-select>
<ng-select ([ngModel])=tab3 *ngIf="tab1" </ng-select>
```

Something like that.